# Delete Row in a table database according to a timestamp from another table

Tags: mysql, database

I'm currently trying to learn how to use procedures with a MySQL database. I have two tables on a testing database, one called users and one called messages.

I tried to erase rows in my messages table if the delete column is equal to 1, using this :

```
DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE `delete` = 1;
```

That worked pretty well.

Then, in my table users, there's a column with a timestamp called last_seen (e.g., 2016-05-08 13:00:26) and another one called user_id, every user has his own unique ID (e.g., 123456789). In my table messages, there's a column called receiver_id. I would like to make a procedure that deletes every row from the table messages where the ID from user_id (in the user table) and receiver_id (in the messages table) matches and if the timestamp date (from the table users and the column last_seen) is older than 30 days.

I tried a couple of different things, but none seemed to work. Any idea how do it ?

This is pretty much my first time trying to use MySQL and this is probably not very optimized, it is for school and learning purposes. I'm trying to make a very basic system that stores users and their messages in a database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could be query like this (join and date_sub)

```
delete from  `messages` 
inner join `user` on `messages`.user_id = `user`.id
and `user`.last_seen < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) ;
```